# PhoneApplicationPage Instance not getting garbage collected

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, garbage-collection, out-of-memory

I am working on a windows phone 8 app and I am getting OutOfMemoryException after some navigations through my app. I tried to find the memory leak using visual studio WP application analysis and found that none of my page instances are getting killed. So I tried a sample application where the only thing I am doing is navigating from the main page to another page and back. I do not have any controls in the page2 and I am not using any view models. After going through a few navigations I found that exactly two instaces of my page2 are there (the last two navigated instaces). No matter how many times I did the navigations and calling GC.Collect() the instances are still there(Only the last two). Why is this happening? Is it the way it is supposed to work?

P.S. I didn't think posting any code was necessary. Tell me if I need to post any.

Comment: How did you see page instances in memory which couldn't be collected by GC? I may want to try on my end as well...

Comment: Are you asking me how I did memory analysis on my application?

Comment: I don't know how to see page instances remain on memory in an analysis session...

Comment: In Visual studio 13 if you go to Debug-> Start Windows Phone Application Analysis you will see options for doing memory analysis on your applciation. See [this](http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2012/02/01/memory-profiling-for-application-performance.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realize that it has page instances stats in Silverlight stuffs...

Comment: Raj: I couldn't reproduce your issue. On my end, trying to force gc collect few times and wait a while, it would collect page2 instances...